# Creating a new record resulting in creating identic new record in related table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Each time I create a new `PurchasedProduct`, and refer a `Product` to it, upon insertion to the table, the table always creates a new identical `Product` and refer to the new one, instead of refering to the existing one.

So, I have these 3 relevant tables :
[image]

..which means that a `Purchase` can have many `PurchasedProduct`, each to represent a purchased `Product` and how many of it purchased (Quantity).

This is the winform :
[image]

These are the relevant codes :

```
public partial class fmAddEditPurchase : Form
{
    List<Product> products;
    Purchase purchase;

    public fmAddEditPurchase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Purchase = new Purchase();
        Text = "Add New Purchase";
        dtpDate.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;

        RefreshPurchasedProduct();
        LoadProductList();
    }

    private void RefreshPurchasedProduct()
    {
        List<PurchasedProduct> ppQuery = new List<PurchasedProduct>();
        BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();

        if (Purchase.PurchasedProducts.Count > 0)
        {
            using (var context = new dbKrunchworkContext())
            {
                bi.DataSource = Purchase.PurchasedProducts.
                    Join(products, x => x.Product, y => y, (x, y) =>
                           new { y.Product_Name, x.Price, x.Quantity }).
                           ToList();
            }
        }

        dgvPurchasedProduct.DataSource = bi;
        dgvPurchasedProduct.Refresh();
    }

    private void LoadProductList()
    {
        using (var context = new dbKrunchworkContext())
        {
            products = context.Products.ToList();
        }

        cbProductName.DataSource = products.
            Select(x => x.Product_Name).ToList();
    }

    private void btAddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal price = 0.0M;

        if (decimal.TryParse(tbPrice.Text, out price) && price > 0)
        {
            PurchasedProduct temp = Purchase.PurchasedProducts.
                FirstOrDefault(
                    x => x.Product == 
                    products[cbProductName.SelectedIndex] &&
                    x.Price == price);

            if (temp == null)
            {
                PurchasedProduct newPP = new PurchasedProduct();

                newPP.Product = products[cbProductName.SelectedIndex];
                newPP.Purchase = Purchase;
                newPP.Quantity = (int)numQuantity.Value;
                newPP.Price = price;

                if (newPP.Product != null)
                {
                    Purchase.PurchasedProducts.Add(newPP);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                temp.Quantity += (int)numQuantity.Value;
            }

            RefreshPurchasedProduct();
        }
    }

    private void btSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Purchase.Received_Date = dtpDate.Value;
            Purchase.Total_Amount = decimal.Parse(tbTotalPrice.Text);
            Purchase.Note = tbNote.Text;

            using (var context = new dbKrunchworkContext())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Purchase.PurchasedProducts.Count; i++)
                {
                    PurchasedProduct pp = 
                        Purchase.PurchasedProducts.ElementAt(i);

                    Product p = context.Products.
                        FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == pp.Product.ID);

                    pp.Product = p;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the main form which insert the new record to the table after receiving `DialogResult() == DialogResult.OK` from above `Form`.

```
    private void Purchase_AddNewRecord()
    {
        fmAddEditPurchase addForm = new fmAddEditPurchase();

        if (addForm.ShowDialog() == 
            DialogResult.OK && addForm.Purchase.Total_Amount > 0)
        {
            using (var context = new dbKrunchworkContext())
            {
                context.Purchases.Add(addForm.Purchase);
                context.SaveChanges();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Example :

Before

[image]

What I did (+ save)

[image]

After (Please note that it creating a new `Product` instead of using the old one)

[image]

Comment: For better maintenability, because you are using Windows Forms, just create one instance of your context as a field of your form. This is better and not error prone like this one you show us.

Comment: This seems to be happening because the `Product` entity it's detached to the context in which your are saving the `PurchasedProduct`. Try attaching it first, then use it as a reference to the `PurchasedProduct` entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multiple instance of your `DbContext` in multiple methods of your form.

You have this issue because the below code will take all objects into the `Purshase` graph and mark all of them into `Added` state.

```
private void Purchase_AddNewRecord()
{
    fmAddEditPurchase addForm = new fmAddEditPurchase();

    if (addForm.ShowDialog() == 
        DialogResult.OK && addForm.Purchase.Total_Amount > 0)
    {
        using (var context = new dbKrunchworkContext())
        {
            context.Purchases.Add(addForm.Purchase);
            context.SaveChanges();
        } 
    }
}
```

To solve this you must change the state of every `Product` instance related to `Purshase` instance like the follwoing code :

```
private void Purchase_AddNewRecord()
{
    fmAddEditPurchase addForm = new fmAddEditPurchase();

    if (addForm.ShowDialog() == 
        DialogResult.OK && addForm.Purchase.Total_Amount > 0)
    {
        using (var context = new dbKrunchworkContext())
        {
            context.Purchases.Add(addForm.Purchase);
            foreach (var purchasedProduct in addForm.Purchase.PurchasedProducts)
            {
                context.Entry(purchasedProduct.Product).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        } 
    }
}
```

It is not recommended, when you are using Windows Forms or WPF, to create a new instance of your `DbContext` into every method like you actually do. You must create just one per form by creating a field for that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Btw, can you explain a bit further on `context.Entry(purchasedProduct.Product).State = EntityState.Unchanged;`? Since I don't get how the code work. Thanks.